# Why doesn't my homepage URL contain a trailing slash in the browser address bar?

Tags: url

When I visit my homepage https://example.com/ in a web browser, the trailing slash doesn't appear in the URL when I view it in the browser address bar:

> https://example.com

However, if I now copy the address from the browser address bar (which is https://example.com) and then paste it out in my text editor, I get a trailing slash appear:

> https://example.com/

Why is the trailing slash absent when I view the URL in the browser address bar, yet not absent when I copy and paste that same URL? I don't believe `.htaccess` rules can explain this behaviour.

Comment: It's just the browser hiding an unimportant character (it'll do the same for the leading `http://` but not for https). Don't overthink it. Nothing to do with server config or .htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why on earth do you think the `.htaccess` file should have anything at all to do with this?

It's a browser behavior and is the same on all sites: If you view the root page of a site, it will only display `example.com` to be easily readable, but it will copy a full, valid [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) like `http://example.com/` into the clipboard, which requires the `/` at the end of the host/port part.